# How can I access which button is clicked in an iteration using php

Tags: php, html

I have used while loop to access the data from the database and also to display it. I even have a button inside the loop.
is there any method to identify which button is clicked inside the iteration using PHP?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
$result = $con->query($sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
   echo $row['userName'];
   echo $row['userId'];  ?>
   
   <input type="submit" value="Check User" name="chkuser" class="btn btn-primary">
<?php } ?>
```

Now how can I identify which button is clicked?

Comment: PHP is purely server side whereas the button is purely client-side. You need Javascript (clientside) to determine which button was clicked (easy btw) otherwise each button would need some unique identifier which is known by PHP and checked in the POST array

Comment: Or if you give each button a unique value and put it inside its own form then you'll know. (Or use a hidden field alongside it in that form to contain the unique value). That's assuming you want PHP to know which button was clicked (whereas the suggestion above assumes you want the browser to know. You didn't clarify the purpose of your requirement.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate the use of Javascript to determine which button was pressed perhaps the following might be useful?

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo $row['userName'];
       echo $row['userId'];
?>
   
   <input type='submit' value='Check User' name='chkuser' class='btn btn-primary' data-user='<?php echo $row['userName'];?>' data-id='<?php echo $row['userId'];?>' />
   
<?php 
    }
?>

<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"][name="chkuser"]').forEach( bttn=>{
        bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(this.dataset.user+'\n'+this.dataset.id)
        })
    })
</script>
```

For example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"][name="chkuser"]').forEach( bttn=>{
  bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.dataset.user+'\n'+this.dataset.id)
  })
})
```

```html
John 23 <input type='submit' value='Check User' name='chkuser' class='btn btn-primary' data-user='john' data-id='23' />
Fred 44<input type='submit' value='Check User' name='chkuser' class='btn btn-primary' data-user='fred' data-id='44' />
Sarah 21<input type='submit' value='Check User' name='chkuser' class='btn btn-primary' data-user='sarah' data-id='21' />
Rebecca 69<input type='submit' value='Check User' name='chkuser' class='btn btn-primary' data-user='rebecca' data-id='69' />
```

It really depends what the ultimate goal is with the knowledge of which button was pressed - presumably to facilitate an `update` of some sort in the db? If that is the case a simple AJAX request rather than the `alert` with the username & userid will help.